# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location: http://localhost:3000/_auth/laravelPassportPassword/token Line Number 1, Column 1

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, laravel-passport, nuxt-auth

I am using nuxt js along with laravel passport. when I logged in it logged in successfully
but it shows the above error and on refresh, it redirects to the login.

In my login.vue

```
methods: {
    async login() {
      this.error = null;
      await this.$auth
        .loginWith("laravelPassportPassword", { data: this.form })
        .then((response) => this.$router.push("/"))
        .catch((error) => (this.error = error.response.data.message));
    },
  },
```

In my nuxt.config.js

```
auth: {
        redirect: {
            home: '/',
        },
        strategies: {
            laravelPassportPasswordGrant: {
                name: 'laravelPassportPassword',
                provider: 'laravel/passport',
                url: '/backend',
                endpoints: {
                    logout: '/api/logout',
                    user: {
                        url: '/api/user',
                    },
                },
                clientId: process.env.PASSPORT_CLIENT_ID,
                clientSecret: process.env.PASSPORT_CLIENT_SECRET,
                grantType: 'password',
            },
        }
```